# Why am I getting an attribute error on numpy simulation?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a function that will solve this question: What is the probability that the minimal die is 3 when 5 dice are cast?

I've run into this error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'min'`, and I can't figure out how to fix it. The code worked fine before I made it a function.

Here is my function:

```
import numpy as np

def minimal_throw(throws, rng, n_reps = 10 ** 5):
    results = rng.integers(low = 1, high = 6 + 1, size = (n_reps, throws))
    minimas = throws.min(axis = 1)
    uniques, counts  = np.unique(minimas, return_counts = True)
    return {"face" : uniques, "probability" : counts / n_reps}

rng = np.random.default_rng()

simulated_throws = minimal_throw(5, rng = rng)
faces = simulated_throws["face"]
probabilities = simulated_throws["probability"]
```

Comment: I expect it to take the minima of every row in the matrix

Comment: There is no matrix in that line.

Comment: `throws` is not a matrix.

Comment: oh ok, I thought it was,  makes sense why I can't have an axis of 1 then

Comment: I think what you want is minimas=results.min(axis=1) not throws.min(...)

Comment: yes, that's right, it works now thx, can you add this comment as an answer?